# window.event.srcElement doesn't work for firefox?

Tags: javascript

The following doesn't work for firefox. I'm trying delete the table row on click. Can anyone please help. Many thanks.

```
<INPUT TYPE="Button" onClick="delRow()" VALUE="Remove">

function delRow(){
   if(window.event){
      var current = window.event.srcElement;
   }else{
      var current = window.event.target;
   }
   //here we will delete the line
   while ( (current = current.parentElement) && current.tagName !="TR");
        current.parentElement.removeChild(current);
}
```

Comment: If you need to do this without a framework for whatever reason, cool, but otherwise you'll save yourself a hell of a lot of trouble due to cross browser compatibility issues by using a framework like jQuery or Prototype

Comment: Not so much for something this simple.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. window.event is IE only. window.event does not exist in W3C standard.
2. event object by default is pass in as the first argument to a event handler with the W3C standard.
3. an inline onlick event in the markup calling a function mean that the event handler is calling that function. With your markup as example. It mean `function() { delRow(); }`. As you can see you won't be able to see the `event` object in `delRow()` except when you are in IE because event is in the window object.
4. parentElement is also IE only, in most case changing it to parentNode would work. Assuming the parent node is also an element.

I suggest you to use javascript library such as jQuery or change your code if you need to keep things relatively the same.

```
<INPUT TYPE="Button" onclick="delRow(event);" VALUE="Remove">

function delRow(e) {
    var evt = e || window.event; // this assign evt with the event object
    var current = evt.target || evt.srcElement; // this assign current with the event target
    // do what you need to do here
}
```

Comment: +1. Actually the way you've done it there, there's no need for the `var evt = e || window.event`, since all browsers will pass the event object to `delRow()`.

Comment: @Tim, you are right. That's because I am used to assigning the event handler directly. e.g. button.onclick = function(e) { //do something };

Comment: "there's no need for the var evt = e || window.event". Not true, `var evt = e || window.event` is a proper cross-browser solution. It can be further simplified to `e = e || window.event`, then use `e` throughout the rest of the function.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `event.target` instead of `window.event.target` to work for Firefox. Try to use the following.

```
<INPUT TYPE="Button" onclick="delRow()" VALUE="Remove">

function delRow(){
   if(window.event){
      var current = window.event.srcElement;
   }else{
      current = event.target;
   }
   //here we will delete the line
   while ( (current = current.parentElement) && current.tagName !="TR");
        current.parentElement.removeChild(current);
}
```

Comment: I think you also need to change the click handler to onclick="delRow(event)"

Answer (score 1):

```
var CurrentObject = 
    0 < window.navigator.appVersion.toString().indexOf("MSIE") 
    ? 
    window.event.srcElement 
    : 
    evt.target;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's [Mozilla's documentation of the Event class](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM:event); might give you some insight.

Answer (score 0):

NEVER use individual browser checks like "check for MSIE".

Do you know how many browsers you'd have to check for... and individual browser VERSIONS... to check them all?

NEVER use jQuery for this either.   Write correct code yourself.  Never include (useless) massive libraries when you aren't going to use 99% of their features anyway.

Answer (score 0):

just found out, works on ie & ff and chrome. others don't know but I expect that this will work on allso the rest. at least hope so :)
As a beginner in html, JS and PHP, it's very annoying that there is not a standard in these things ! even styling a simple div element can be a headage because of the behavior is not allways the same on different browsers !?

```
function somefunc()
{
  var callerelement = arguments.callee.caller.arguments[0].target;
  alert(callerelement.id)
}
```