# Event handling with Firefox

Tags: javascript, events, firefox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [window.event.srcElement doesn’t work for firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209654/window-event-srcelement-doesnt-work-for-firefox)

I made a web page that works fine with Chrome, but doesn't with Firefox.
Here's the code:

```
function set_email_params(e){
if(!e)
    e=window.Event;   //window.event appeared to be "undefined" so I had to use Event
alert(e.target);        //shows "undefined"
alert(e.target.src);
if(e.target.src.indexOf("unchecked")>-1)
    e.target.src='images/small_radio_checked.png';
else
    e.target.src='images/small_radio_unchecked.png';
}
```

Here's how the function is called:

```
  <img onclick="set_email_params()" src="images/small_radio_unchecked.png" style="float:left;"/>
```

This code works perfectly on Chrome.
Please help me.

Comment: How is `set_email_params` getting called?  Is it called as a result of some kind of UI event?  (eg: Button click?)

Comment: Yes it's called when you click on an image.

Comment: `e=window.Event;` is wrong. Use `if (!e) e=window.event;` even if `window.event` is `undefined`.

Comment: @user1689607 if it's `undefined` there is some really important code missing from the post

Comment: @Esailija: It *should* be `undefined` since it's non-standard. There's a `window.Event` function, but that won't be of use here.

Comment: @Esailija OK I'll add the HTML part, but it's really strange that everything works fine on Chrome

Comment: It sounds like `e` should always be a valid event and you should never need to test it.  If it isn't, then some other part of your code has failed.  `window.Event` is most likely the global Event object constructor, which isn't helpful to you here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not passing the `event` object in the handler.

```
onclick="set_email_params(event)"
   <!---------------------^^^^^--------->
```

---

In a standards compliant browser, the event handler will end up looking something like this:

```
function(event) {
    set_email_params(event);
}
```

While in older IE it'll look more like this:

```
function() {
    set_email_params(event);
}
```

So either way, the event object will be passed on.

Comment: Still weird that it works on chrome, unless he has `window.event` (which is defined in chrome)

Comment: @Esailija: Yeah, I don't understand that, unless they actually add properties to `window.Event` in order to "prevent" bugs.

Comment: @Esailija: Oh, wait, it works in Chrome because `if (!e) ` will fail. ...ugh, nevermind ...I'm confusing myself. He wasn't passing the event object, so it would clearly pass.

Comment: @user1689607 in his original code `if( !e )` is always `true` and the `e = window.Event` branch is taken because the function is not passed any arguments, no?

Comment: @Esailija: Yeah, I just updated my comment when I realized that. I have [*The Proclaimers*](http://www.amazon.com/Im-Gonna-Be-500-Miles/dp/B000T1EJ0W/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1353361831&s=dmusic&sr=1-1) blasting in my ears right now, so I'll blame it on them. :)

Comment: He probably just thought he had `window.Event`, but was actually still using a cached file with `window.event`, as that's the only realistic way his original code will work in chrome. Mystery solved :P

Comment: @Esailija: I'm satisfied with that explanation. :-)