# Proper way to assign to events in asp.net webforms programatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, user-controls

I needed a tree view that has checkboxes, asynchronously gets data to populate the nodes when they are expanded, and automatically checks/unchecks child/parent nodes appropriately as checkboxes are clicked.

The only part that didn't work out of the box was the checking/unchecking of child/parent nodes when their children/parent nodes are clicked. While there is an event available for when a checkbox is clicked, it doesn't automatically post back so I added some javascript to make it do so.

It was working really well when I was getting data directly from the control, but when I decided to refactor the control so I could use it in other places I decided to create an event that consuming code would assign to in order to provide the control a way to get data from the right place.

I assign to my event on the Page_Load of the page the control is on, and this works for expanding nodes just fine because the event gets assigned to again at the beginning of each post back. However, when I click a checkbox the Page_Load event for the page the control is on doesn't get called and so the event doesn't get assigned to.

I've already planned to implement an alternate solution that will use jQuery to do the checking/unchecking on the client side without posting back, but I'd really like to know the proper design pattern for handling this kind of situation.

Below is the aspx that shows how I'm making it post back. I can post other code if needed or if my explanation wasn't clear.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="DepartmentTreeView.ascx.cs" Inherits="TrainUp.Web.Lms.Mtv.Controls.RequiredTraining.DepartmentTreeView" %>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        <%-- This is used to cause a postback when a checkbox is clicked, 
             which allows the DepartmentTree_TreeNodeCheckChanged event to get raised --%>
        function postBackByObject() {
            var o = window.event.srcElement;
            if (o.tagName == "INPUT" && o.type == "checkbox") {
                __doPostBack("", "");
            }
        }

    </script>

    <asp:TreeView ID="DepartmentTree" SkinId="Contacts" runat="server" 
            OnTreeNodePopulate ="DepartmentTree_TreeNodePopulate" 
            OnTreeNodeCheckChanged="DepartmentTree_TreeNodeCheckChanged"
            OnClick="javascript:postBackByObject()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't add comments yet but it sounds as you aren't putting your code on the right state of the page life cycle to render your treeview again. You can reuse the treeview using a webcontrol or encapsulating all the logic on a js file and referencing it on every page you need to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I don´t see the problem and the code should work just fine. However, I recommend to change your javascript code though because it won´t work in Firefox ([window.event.srcElement doesn't work for firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209654/window-event-srcelement-doesnt-work-for-firefox))

```
function postBackByObject(e) {
    var evt = e || window.event;
    var o = evt.target;
    if (o.tagName == "INPUT" && o.type == "checkbox") {
        __doPostBack("", "");
    }
}

<asp:TreeView ID="DepartmentTree" runat="server" ShowCheckBoxes="All"
     ShowExpandCollapse="true"
     OnTreeNodePopulate="DepartmentTree_TreeNodePopulate"
     OnTreeNodeCheckChanged="DepartmentTree_TreeNodeCheckChanged"
     OnClick="postBackByObject(event);" />
```

Comment: Good to know. I guess I wasn't completely clear though as the problem isn't with the code posted... just showed that so the reader would know how I was doing the post back in case it was relevant to how the Page_Load was(n't) being called.